# Java Streams - check if list is null

Tags: java, java-stream

I wonder what's teh best approach to check if list is null. In my Stream I call `orElseThrow` twice. It works but I don;t know if its correct? It looks a little bit ugly:

```
Optional.ofNullable(listCanBeNull)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("the same error message"))
                .stream()
                .filter(configuration -> configuration.getId().equals(warehouseConfigurationId))
                .findAny()
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("the same error message"));
```

I have to throw error when list is null and when no item was found

Comment: The Java stream interface is convenient, but it doesn't have to consume your entire program. Sometimes the most readable thing is a good old-fashioned `if (list == null) { throw blah; }` at the start of your loop.

Comment: Just use CollectionUtils.isEmpty and MapUtils.isEmpty()

Comment: And for starters, a `List` shouldn't be `null`, it should be empty instead.

Comment: OK, thanks maybe I tried to use Streams by force :)

Comment: BTW you can remove first exception throwing. Instead of `.orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("the same error message")).stream()` use `.stream().flatMap(List::stream)` which in case of null list (so empty Optional) will create empty stream. So since no value will be found it will be indicated by last `orElseThrow`.

Comment: Yeah, after change I have if else that check for null and then Stream without Optional

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An Optional.ofNullable can be turned into a (possibly empty) Stream, or you can immediately use Stream.ofNullable. And do a flatMap.

```
Stream.ofNullable(listCanBeNull)
        .stream()
        .flatMap()
        .filter(configuration -> couration.getId().equals(warehouseConfigurationId))
        .findAny()
        .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("the same error message"));
```

Answer (score 5):

Just check if the list is null directly.  Streaming elements from a list only makes sense if the list exists in the first place.

```
if(null != listCanBeNull) {
    // stream things from here
}
```

Comment: Or, `if ( Objects.nonNull( list ) ) { … }`

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
Objects.requireNonNull( list , "error message" ).stream() …  // Throws NullPointerException if null.
```

## Details

If you choose to go with a simple null check before streaming, here is an alternative to the null check shown in correct [Answer by Makoto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73405876/642706).

## `Objects.nonNull`

I find a call to [`Objects.nonNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#nonNull(java.lang.Object)) to be more readable than `null != list`.

```
if ( Objects.nonNull( list ) ) { list.stream() … }
```

## `Objects.requireNonNull`

Or automatically throw an exception if the object reference should never be null, with a call to [`Objects.requireNonNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull(T)).

```
 Objects.requireNonNull( list )  // Throws NullPointerException if null.
```

This method returns the object you pass (your list), providing for convenient [method-chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining).

```
Objects.requireNonNull( list ).stream() …
```

You can optionally pass a message to be used in the exception if thrown.

```
Objects.requireNonNull( list , "message goes here" ).stream() …
```